# Unexpected Values in Byte Objects

Tags: python

The following byte object is an echo reply from a ping program:

```
b'E \x00\x1c\x021\x00\x007\x01=\x9fJ}\xefr\n\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What does the "E" at the beginning mean and why do I see sequences as such "efr" or "9fJ}"?

Also, I tried reading the documentation and the document that specifies the purpose of the byte object (apparently they felt strings were overloaded) and they didn't really say in absolute terms this is what byte objects are for. Can you please specificy the exact purpose of byte objects?

What would be the difference between:

```
b'\x00\x1c\x021'
```

and just doing this:

```
'\x00\x1c\x021'
```

Answer (score 0):

The E at the beginning is simply the character E, that is a byte with the value 69. `\xef` is a byte with the hexadecimal value EF and thus the decimal value 239. The r after it is again simply the letter r. Similarly `\x9fJ}` is `\x9f`, followed by J, followed by }.

The difference between `b'\x00\x1c\x021'` and `'\x00\x1c\x021'` is that one is a bytes object and one is a string that will print simply as "1" because it contains several non-printable characters.

Comment: Why doesn't the E at the beginning have to be escaped as hex? The confusion is coming from "\x" then. When do we use that? So if the "J" is just ascii, in the byte it just has the value of the ascii "J"?

Comment: @user3806518 Why would it have to be escaped? It doesn't have any special meaning in string or byte literals. You use `\x` when you want to have a byte with the given value and there is no printable/easily typable character with that value (or you don't want to rely on the readers of your code to know the byte values of a given character from the top of their heads - assuming the byte value, not the character, is relevant to the meaning of the code).

Comment: Wait... The first byte of an echo reply should be 0x00... You said E is 69? Decimal? Does this mean E is encoded as UTF-16?